# how to get a if else to operate based on the char i entered

Tags: java

am trying to get an if else if statement to operate but am getting an error when using it please see the program below thanks

```
public class Info {

  public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter employee num");
    int e_num=input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter employee first name");
    String e_fname=input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter employee surname");
    String e_sname=input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter employee code C or c,H or h and F or f");
    char e_code = input.next().charAt(0);

   if(e_code==F||e_code==f){
       e_code==monthly_paid;
   }            
 }
}
```

Comment: `if(e_code == 'F' || e_code == 'f')` would probably work better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're just looking for *character literals* to compare your variable against:

```
if (e_code == 'F' || e_code == 'f')
```

(The spacing isn't required - it's just for readability...)

On the other hand, given that you've got a fixed set of options, you may well want a switch/case instead.

This doesn't look ideal though:

```
e_code==monthly_paid;
```

What's `monthly_paid` here? Why would you want to change the variable representing the *code* entered by the user into something that sounds like an amount of money?

Comment: @KernDennis: "an error" isn't really helpful. You need to give details. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 1):

In your code many problem is there

1. you are comparing character literals against variable
2. The variable it self is not declared. If you write `e_code == F` then compiler will treat F as variable not as literal.
3. In your code `e_code==monthly_paid;` in java `==` is not use to assign value for assigning value you have to use `e_code = monthly_paid;` **=** operator.
4. Your `monthly_paid` variable is also not declared.